# Downloading a file does not work in subscribe after GET request

Tags: angular, download, observable

I am attempting to download a PDF that is generated by my server when a user clicks on a download button. I have gotten this to work, but it does not seem like best practice since the PDF opens in a new window using a server URL:

```
  public exportPdf() {

      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.hidden = true;
      link.target = '_blank;';
      link.download = 'test.pdf';
      link.href = `blob:http://localhost:3333/pdf`;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
      link.remove();

    }
```

So now I am trying to instead use a generated front-end URL, but the PDF window never opens. I am able to go to the console link that is printed out, and see my PDF just fine. Am I missing something else in this second implementation?

```
public exportPdf() {

      this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:3333/pdf`, { responseType: 'blob' } )
      .subscribe(response => {

        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.hidden = true;
        link.target = '_blank;';
        link.download = 'test.pdf';
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
        console.log({link})


        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        link.remove();

      })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
window['saveAs'](response, 'filename');
```

[edit1]
Look at this post as well: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)